# Calling super.onStop() in onRestart()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

The following code, which is from Messaging app of AOSP, calls super.onStop() in onRestart() at line 84
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/messaging/ui/BugleActionBarActivity.java#81 (Since this code has been around for years, I'm assuming this is not a bug but deliberate).
What is the use of this? Is this some pattern providing a shortcut?

Comment: This is definitely a bug

Comment: Definitely a bug o-o